# Why IndexOf(Object) in the redux case of React App is work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I was using the `indexOf()` method to find the Object in Array finely.

Until the moment I looked up some information and found the code should be not work unexpectedly.

I tried the code following above in `reducer` and it was work

```
let tmp = state.find(x=> x.id == action.payload.id);
let index = state.indexOf(tmp);
console.log(index); // it is not -1
```

But I tried the code in the `React Component` and chrome console is not work

```
let a = [{id: 1, value:"foo"}, {id: 2, value:"bar"}];
console.log(a.indexOf({id: 1, value:"foo"})); // it is -1
```

I can't understand why the result is different.

Do I need to modify the code in the `redux` case?

Comment: you can't pass the whole object in the `indexOf` method to find it. Do same like the `tmp`. `a.find(x => x.id == 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in first case you trying to find object that exist in array, var tmp refers to this object. in second - you create new object, it does not exist in array, it just "equal" to some object in array.

Answer (score 0):

> syntax object.indexOf compare value by reference:

Reference type comparison only true value when both value  belong to same pointer

ex:

```
a = [{id: 1, value:"foo"}, {id: 2, value:"bar"}];
aCopy = a.slice(0,1)[0]      // reference by val
console.log(a.indexOf(aCopy)) // 0
```

> Case 2: comparison by Value type,  the code you have written is comparing
>   values by value type not reference type

```
  let tmp = state.find(x=> x.id == action.payload.id);   // here comparison is done by value not by pointer(memory location)
  let index = state.indexOf(tmp);
  console.log(index); // it is not -1
```